# Vagrant-lxc container not starting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualization, lxc

Firstly I'd like to say that I'm new to LXC and I may have some problems getting the right idea of how the things should work. The thing is I'm trying to start a previously download vagrant-lxc box that holds an Ubuntu 12.04 x32. My development PC is running Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and lxc 1.0.0.alpha1 installed from the Ubuntu official repositories.
When I run vagrant up --provider=lxc I'm always getting

```
There was an error executing ["sudo", "lxc-create",
"--template", "vagrant-tmp-lxc-test_default-1393431786",
"--name", "lxc-test_default-1393431786",
"-f", "/home/ccvera/.vagrant.d/boxes/lxc-ubuntu-12.04/lxc/lxc.conf",
"--", "--tarball", "/home/ccvera/.vagrant.d/boxes/lxc-ubuntu-12.04/lxc/rootfs.tar.gz",
"--auth-key", "/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/keys/vagrant.pub"]
```

I might be making a dumb error here so my questions are:

1. Is there any problem running a box of x32 container inside a x64 host using LXC?
2. Is there any problem running a box with a different Ubuntu version (Kernel version) that the host machine does? In may case (Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 2.6) vs Ubuntu 13.10 (kernel 3.11))
3. In the case that 1, 2 do not apply, then, how can I figure out what's the problem? prepending `VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG` didn't make the trick, it just shows the above errors many times.
4. In the case that 1 or 2 do apply, then, how can I overcome the situation?, I need fast and well performance on test virtual machines, (so I think I need containers), but it is not feasible to me that the developers should have the same OS as the testing VMs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to newer versions of lxc and vagrant-lxc did the trick.

And after some reading is seems that x32 box runs under x64 host kernel so it becomes on a x64 box, that's the idea of containers.